# Undefined reference to 'glewExperimental' and 'glewInit'

Tags: linux, opengl, glew

My Program in OpenGL on a Linux system (Ubuntu) has the following problem. I am unable to understand.

**CODE :**

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

   if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
   {
      std::cerr<<"GLEW Initialization failed"<<std::endl;
      return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**ERROR :**

```
/tmp/ccw4KIKB.o: In function `main':
Experimental.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
Experimental.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `glewInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**COMPILING :**

```
g++ Experimental.cpp -lglfw -lGL
```

Comment: Try `-lglfw3` instead of `-lglfw`

Comment: Try adding `-lGLEW` to your compile/link command.

Comment: @G.M. I have no idea how or why but using `-lGLEW` works. Could you kindly tell me as to why this is happening? Because there is no directory named **GLEW** in my **_include_** directory.

Comment: @AtishPratapSinghRathour Just as you need to link with `libglfw` to get `glfwCreateWindow` etc., so you need to link with `libGLEW` to get functions such as `glewInit` and so on.